# Jquery, Indicate div transformation and display it's current position continuously

Tags: jquery

I try to catch the current position of some elements (which is always changed by css animation). I try this(see code below), but it's not catch the position continuously (I should refresh the page everytime i want to know the current position). So how to do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
    div#divx {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        top: 15px;
        animation-name: xxx;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    @keyframes xxx {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(0px);
        }
        50% {
            transform: translateX(100px);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translateX(0px);
        }
    }

    div#divy {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        top: 15px;
        animation-name: yyy;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    @keyframes yyy {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(100px);
        }
        50% {
            transform: translateX(0px);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translateX(100px);
        }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="divx"></div>

<div id="divy"></div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p id="xposition">x</p>

<p id="yposition">y</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var xmove = $("#divx").position();
        var ymove = $("#divy").position();

        $('#xposition').html('Black X Position = ' + xmove.left);
        $('#yposition').html('Blue X Position = ' + ymove.left);

    })
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var xmove = $("#divx").position();
    var ymove = $("#divy").position();

    $('#xposition').html('Black X Position = ' + xmove.left);
    $('#yposition').html('Blue X Position = ' + ymove.left);
}, 100);
```

**Full Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      div#divx {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        top: 15px;
        animation-name: xxx;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        z-index: -1;
      }

      @keyframes xxx {
        0% {
          transform: translateX(0px);
        }
        50% {
          transform: translateX(100px);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translateX(0px);
        }
      }

      div#divy {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        top: 15px;
        animation-name: yyy;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      }

      @keyframes yyy {
        0% {
          transform: translateX(100px);
        }
        50% {
          transform: translateX(0px);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translateX(100px);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="divx"></div>

    <div id="divy"></div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id="xposition">x</p>

    <p id="yposition">y</p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
          var xmove = $("#divx").position();
          var ymove = $("#divy").position();

          $('#xposition').html('Black X Position = ' + xmove.left);
          $('#yposition').html('Blue X Position = ' + ymove.left); 
        }, 100)


      })
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function () {
    var xmove = $("#divx").position();
    var ymove = $("#divy").position();

    $('#xposition').html('Black X Position = ' + xmove.left);
    $('#yposition').html('Blue X Position = ' + ymove.left); 
  }, 100)


})
```

```css
div#divx {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  animation-name: xxx;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes xxx {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

div#divy {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 15px;
  animation-name: yyy;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes yyy {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divx"></div>

<div id="divy"></div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p id="xposition">x</p>

<p id="yposition">y</p>
```

Comment: But, actually  what I want to achieve is to "catch" the current position continuously,, not just display it.. so when the black box is at certain position (example: xmove==100), I want to add some event, like changing it's color, or whatever. With setInterval method, it's hard to do, because it need to exact. Decrease the interval is not helping and sometimes cause the interval method stop.

Comment: @HudoyoDanumurti Got it. You need to bind using some animation event. Lemme get it for you.

Comment: @HudoyoDanumurti Found it: [**How to Capture CSS3 Animation Events in JavaScript**](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/)

Comment: I think setInterval is vulnerable to error and lag? Btw I just study the link you sent, it seems it is what I want, but I'm not sure yet.. Actually I want to make a game like fighting game, with Artificial Intelligence as the enemy. Imagine the black box is moved by player and the blue box is the AI, and you change those background image with sprites.. when the player and enemy is in certain position, i'll change the background image (with another sprite, maybe punching or whatever). By setInterval, it could be work, but sometimes not (due to lagging)

Comment: I think I will make the movement block by block..thank you anyway! :))